# How to call a method whenever an entry of an array-type property is changed?

Tags: c#, validation, properties

I have a property of type `double[]` with a public get and set accessor. I would like to call some input check whenever one element of the array is changed.

I have tried the following:

```
private double[] myArray;

public double[] MyArray
{
    get { return myArray; }
    set 
    {
        CheckInput(value);
        myArray = value;
    }
}
```

However, when I run for example `classInstance.MyArray[3] = 5;` the `CheckInput` method is not called (which makes sense, as the array is only *modified* but not re-set to a new object).

Comment: You need an observable collection, not an array.

Comment: Array properties should be read-only. Being able to set the property means being able to replace the entire array with a new one. Modifying an element means getting the property value and then setting the element of that, not setting the property. You should almost never use arrays for property types unless they are generated on demand, e.g. `TextBox.Lines`. You should generally have a read-only property of a collection type. As suggested, if you need to be notified when the list contents changes then that's exactly what an `ObservableCollection` is for.

Comment: Your property setter will be called if you replace the whole array in your parent object, but not if you replace an item within your array.

Comment: You need to route your array updates through a method that performs any other actions you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you will know the index and value anytime you are trying to set the array, you could have a method that you call instead:

```
public void UpdateMyArray(int index, double value){

    MyArray[index] = value;
    // Do other things here

}
```

If that doesn't work for you, it's possible to create your own array type and have an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/6x16t2tx(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#indexers-overview) attached to that new array class, but it would probably be easier to implement an [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 3):

Raw arrays cannot be intercepted. You can, however, add your own indexer *instead of* exposing the raw array:

```cs
private double[] myArray;

public double this[int index]
{
    get { return myArray[index]; }
    set 
    {
        // your per-element validation here, using 'value' and 'index'
        myArray[index] = value;
    }
}
```

The caller would then use `yourObj[index]` to talk to the indexer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe create your own double[] class and overload the indexer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var extArray = new ExtendedArray<double>(10);
        extArray[0] = 2.5;
    }

    public class ExtendedArray<T>
    {
        private T[] _array;

        public ExtendedArray(int size)
        {
            _array = new T[size];
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get => _array[index];
            set
            {
                _array[index] = value;
                // Do other stuff here
            }
        }
    }
```